# How can I do multipart/form-data request with hash key?

Tags: node.js, request, hmac

There are how I generate options for the request to the server:

```
function multipartFormData(params, url, key, nonce, signature) {
var boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary' + nonce;
var bodyString = [];

bodyString.push(
'--' + boundary,
'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="image.png"',
'Content-Type: image/png',
'',
fs.createReadStream('image/image.png')
  );

  bodyString.push('--' + boundary + '--','');

  var content = bodyString.join('\r\n');

  return {
    formData: content,
    url: url + '/',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary,
    'Apiauth-Key': key,
    'Apiauth-Nonce': nonce,
    'Apiauth-Signature': signature,
    'Content-Length': content.length
    }
  }
}
```

There are the signature hash authentication key:

```
function getMessageSignature(path, params, nonce) {
    var data_params = params;
    var boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary' + nonce;
    var postParameters  = querystring.stringify(data_params);
    var path = '/api' + path + '/';

    let message = nonce + config.key + path + 'POSTmultipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary + 'image.png';


    var auth_hash = crypto.createHmac("sha256", config.secret).update(message).digest('hex').toUpperCase();
    return auth_hash;
}
```

So then I just do my request:

```
function Client(key, secret) {
    var nonce = new Date() * 1000;
    var config = {
        url: 'https://somesite/api',
        key: key,
        secret: secret
    };

// there is other all functions, 2 of them i have already written on top

    var signature = getMessageSignature(path, params, nonce);
    var options = multipartFormData(params, config.url, config.key, nonce, signature);

    request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I am getting this error in the request body.error :

> message: 'HMAC authentication key and signature was given, but they
>   are invalid

Comment: Where does the message format for the HMAC input come from?

Comment: i have added some explanations, i wrote a trimmed version, if u change multipart/form to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, this code will work

Comment: @Jumper could you fix that after all?